# Getting / Setting values of recycler view items from Activity / Fragment

Tags: android, adapter

I have a Fragment, and I need to run a method from the Fragment and change the value of the recycler view item. 
The problem is that I don't know how to access variables of items in the recycler view from the activity since the items are powered by the adapter and not the activity itself and since the only thing the activity/ Fragment does is to initialise the Recyclerview.

And my main objective here is to change the textview of each items from the fragment.

Is there a way around this?

The function I want to run (In fragment) :

```
  public void countDown(String date) {

    DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    DateTime nextMeeting = Utilities.convertDate(date);

    Duration duration = new Duration(today, nextMeeting);

    new CountDownTimer(duration.getMillis(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           //setting the item textview each time the timer ticks.
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           // setting the item textview when the timer finishes.
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Adapter :

```
 public class UpcomingProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UpcomingProductAdapter.UpcomingProductViewHolder> {

public UpcomingFragment fragment;
public ArrayList<ProductData> products = new ArrayList<>();

public UpcomingProductAdapter(UpcomingFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

public void addProducts(ArrayList<ProductData> products) {
    this.products.addAll(products);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearProduct() {
    products.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public UpcomingProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(fragment.getContext()),
            R.layout.item_upcoming_product,
            parent,
            false
    );
    return new UpcomingProductViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UpcomingProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindProduct(products.get(position), position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}


class UpcomingProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding;

    UpcomingProductViewHolder(ItemUpcomingProductBinding binding) {
        super(binding.getRoot());
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    public ItemUpcomingProductBinding getBinding() {
        return binding;
    }



    void bindProduct(ProductData product, int position) {
        binding.setViewModel(new UpcomingProductViewModel(fragment, binding, product));
    }
}
```

Sorry for the long post.
I've been having this problem for days now and I hope you guys have a solution.
Thanks~~

Answer (score 0):

Add method to your UpcomingProductAdapter.

```
public void updateProduct(int position, Product product) {
    this.products.set(position, product);
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

And then in your fragment use your adapter to change it.

```
  public void countDown(String date) {

    DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    DateTime nextMeeting = Utilities.convertDate(date);

    Duration duration = new Duration(today, nextMeeting);

    new CountDownTimer(duration.getMillis(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
           //setting the item textview each time the timer ticks.
           adapter.updateProduct(somePosition, someProduct);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
           // setting the item textview when the timer finishes.
        }
    }.start();
}
```

In your code you may have memory leaks, so try to read about it. Also I prefere to use `ObservableArrayList` http://blog.trsquarelab.com/2016/01/data-binding-in-android-recyclerview.html

Comment: ya, that is actually the reason why I want to use the countdown method in my fragment rather than in each item in the list. I actually can and have already implemented the timer in each item but there are memory leaks which lead to the list not scrolling properly (laggy) as more items loads in the list

Answer (score 0):

1. You can store a reference to the fragment when you attach it to the activity. Then call the method on this reference.
2. Or you can just do this:

`((YourFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByID(R.id.yourContainer))
                .countDown(date);`